# Unreported Exception/this() need to be first statement

Tags: java, exception

i m writing a very simple java class and i faced a weird problem, i know there are many simple way to resolve it but now i have a doubt

```
public class Frazione {
    private int num;
    private int den;

    public Frazione(int x, int y) throws FrazioneException {
        if (y == 0) {
            throw new FrazioneException();
        }
        num = x;
        den = y;
    }

    /*public Frazione(int x){                   THAT'S HOW IT SHOULD BE BASED
                                                ON THE EXCERCISE BUT IT WON'T
                                                COMPILE BECAUSE THIS ISN'T THE
                                                FIRST STATEMENT
        try{
            this(x,1);
        }catch(FrazioneException e){
            System.err.print("errore: "+e);
        }
    }*/
    /*public Frazione(int x){
            this(x,1);                         IF I TRY THIS WAY I'LL BE IN
                                               AN UNREPORTED EXCEPTION PROBLEM
    }*/
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public int getDen() {
        return den;
    }
}
```

there's a way to use try and catch with this() statement?

Comment: Why don't you throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (that inherits from RuntimeException) instead of your checked exception FrazioneException ?

Comment: What about
`public Frazione(int x)  throws FrazioneException {
        this(x,1);
}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this doesn't work. You'd have to fulfill two contradictory requirements:

1. the `this` call has to be the first statement
2. the `this` call has to be in a `try..catch` statement.

So this can't be solved.

What you could do:

- If you want to throw a checked exception in the constructor, throw it also in the other one. But that doesn't make real sense, because it will never been thrown, because you never pass `y=0`
- Convert `FrazioneException` to a runtime exception and remove `throws`.
- Try to solve your requirement without throwing an exception from the constructor (I usually avoid that because it often causes too much trouble. Like the one you have)

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple constructors and you are using *this* keyword within a constructor to call another constructor, the invocation of another constructor (*this()*) must be the first line of the constructor.